# Output from Javascript function is wrong

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to JavaScript and am trying to create a button that would ask the user the temperature in Fahrenheit, and then a function that would convert it to Celsius. The button seems to be working properly, and the function does something- just not what I need it to. Instead of showing the converted temperature, the function says "NaN". I ran it through the Firefox debugger and there were no error messages, which leads me to believe I've done something very obviously wrong.

```js
function FahToCel() {
  var fah = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ftemp").value);
  var cel = ("ftemp" - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0;
  document.getElementById("DegC").innerHTML = ("The temperature is " + cel + "in Celsius.");
}
```

```html
<form>
  DegF: <br>
  <input type="text" id="ftemp">
  <input value="Calculate" name="Calculate" type=button onClick="FahToCel()">
  <p id="DegC">
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: `"ftemp" - 32.0` should be `fah - 32.0` - and also do cel.toFixed(2) or Math.floor(cel)

Comment: Why are you subtracting a float *from a string*?

Comment: Like I said, I'm very new to Javascript and am trying to learn it on my own. I appreciate all the responses, I figured it would be something obvious to more adept users.

Comment: You're getting `NaN`, not `Nanin`. The `in` is from your own code `in Celsius.` since you put no space before it. `NaN` is a JavaScript error for `Not a Number`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass variable not string:

```
function FahToCel() {
  var fah = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ftemp").value);
  var cel = (fah - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0;
  document.getElementById("DegC").innerHTML = ("The temperature is " + cel + "in Celsius.");
}
```